# How does HTTP download work?

Tags: http, download

Let's say i want to download a file called example.pdf from  [http://www.xxx.ууу/example.pdf](http://www.xxx.%D1%83%D1%83%D1%83/example.pdf)

Probably, i send  GET request like this:

```
GET /example.pdf HTTP/1.1␍␊
 Host: www.xxx.yyy␍␊
 ␍␊
```

But what's next?

How does exchange of http headers look like?

Comment: Use wireshark and see. www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've read the Wikipedia article on the HTTP protocol. If you just need more examples I'd highly recommend you download Wireshark. Wireshark is an extremely powerful packet sniffer which will allow you to watch packet communications between you and any website. In addition it will actually break down the packets and tell you a little bit about their meanings in more "human terms". It has a bit of a learning curve but it can teach you a lot about a number of different protocols including HTTP.

http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Could you point more specifically in the wikipedia article on HTTP where this information is displayed. I'm having the same question but wikipedia's article doesn't seem to explain this in details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is, but you can view real-time http header interaction with the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) Firefox add-on. It's also possible in Chrome, but it's a little more [work](http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2011/06/02/how-to-access-raw-http-headers-in-chrome/).

Answer (score 1):

To answer such GET request, the packet with the following header should be passed:

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 6475593
Content-Type: application/x-msdownload
Etag: "qwfw473usll"
Last-Modified: Sun, 18 Jul 2021 12:02:31 GMT
Server: Caddy
Date: Sun, 18 Jul 2021 12:03:47 GMT
```

After the last line, you must specify 2 CRLF and row bytes of the file to be transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html .  But also, there is rarely a need to recreate the protocol.

Comment: "...rarely a need to recreate the protocol" - This depends pretty highly on the environment and languages being used.